# Case matching with R's gsub?

Tags: regex, r

I am trying to write a code in R to change all "non" word to "none" in a string but I don't want to change any other words, specially I don't want to change "none" to "nonee".

I tried this code:

```
gsub("non","none", "non none", fixed = TRUE)
```

but result is:

```
"none nonee"
```

Is there anyway to do this using R's gsub?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use word boundaries...

```
x <- c("non" , "none")
gsub( "\\bnon\\b" , "none" , x )
#[1] "none" "none"
```

Comment: What was wrong with x <- c("non" , "none")
gsub( "^non$" , "none" , x ) ?

Comment: @Soroosh what do you expect to happen with a string such as `"I wanted non other than the best"`? `^` and `$` anchor the start and end of the entire string respectively. `\\b` just anchors either side of the word bondary.

Comment: I want to change it to "I wanted none other than the best" - thanks I got the point